# I have no idea on how to check for matching numbers

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to C# and was tasked recently with creating a basic lottery program that allows the user to enter six numbers, this is then checked against a table that displays 52 weeks worth of lottery numbers each with 6 numbers. I have this portion of the code done however there is another task that requires me to choose the week in which the user had the most matches and this is where my code skills are really lacking. Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] thelottery = new int[52];
    int[] usernumbers = new int[6];
    Random rnd = new Random();

    Console.Write("Please enter six numbers for the lottery: \n");
    usernumbers[0] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    usernumbers[1] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    usernumbers[2] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    usernumbers[3] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    usernumbers[4] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    usernumbers[5] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("\nYour numbers are: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} ", usernumbers[i]);
    }

    Console.Write("\n\nPress any key to view the results of the lottery: ");
    Console.ReadKey();

    for (int limit  = 0; limit < 52; limit++)
    {
        for (int weeks = 0; weeks < 6; weeks++)
        {
            thelottery[weeks] = rnd.Next(49) + 1;
            Console.Write("\t{0} ", thelottery[weeks]);

        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\n\nYour week with the most matches was...");

    Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress any key to continue: ");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: you have one error, if the user put one letter o signs the sistema will throw an excepction in this line Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());.... use one String and try to convert to int ;)

Comment: Yeah I tried parsing the code to begin with but it ended up giving errors, I'll try your way instead. :)

Comment: Exceptions may already be too advanced, this is supposed to be an entry-level exercise. Where exactly are you stuck? Getting the week with the most matches? After generating he lottery numbers for each week, see how many of these numbers apper in the `usernumbers` array, and keep track of the week in which there were the most matches. (`if(hits_this_week  > maxhits) maxhits = hits_this_week`, by maximum principle)

Comment: Yeah its the getting the week with the most matches part that I'm stuck on, so that should go at the end outside of the for loops and it compares the values inside them with `usernumbers`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case you need a reference solution:

```
    Console.Write("\n\nPress any key to view the results of the lottery: ");
    Console.ReadKey();

    int best_week = 0;
    int best_matches = 0; 

    /* Compute lottery numbers for 52 weeks */
    for (int limit  = 0; limit < 52; limit++)
    {
        /* Compute the 6 lottery numbers for this week */
        for (int weeks = 0; weeks < 6; weeks++)
        {
            thelottery[weeks] = rnd.Next(49) + 1;
            Console.Write("\t{0} ", thelottery[weeks]);
        }

        /* Compute the amount of matches for this week. */
        int matches = 0; 
        //Check each usernumber with each lottery number for a match
        for(int i=0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            //e.g. for i=0, check how many times usernumbers[0] appears in thelottery[].
            for(int j=0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                if(usernumbers[i] == thelottery[j])
                    matches++;
            }
        }

        /* Did we have more matches this week than previosuly recorded? */
        if(matches > best_matches){
            /* yes, remember the new best week and the number of matches. */
            best_week = limit; 
            bist_matches = matches;
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    /* Here, the result of the best week and the best matches is avaiable! */
```

Answer (score 0):

Break the problem down into simple steps. You need to know which week the user had the most matches. 
To do that you need to know

- How many matches the user had each week?
- What was the highest number of matches for that year (and which week it was in)?

Think about what data you need. In a simple program like this, I would probably store the number of matches against the week number i.e.
week 1 : 0 matches
week 2 : 3 matches
week 4 : 6 matches... Woohoo!
and so on.

In C#, the easiest way to do this is to use a `Dictionary<int, int>`.

That should be enough for you to figure out the rest yourself.

Comment: I've really only done the basics and haven't covered the `dictionary` code however the way you described breaking it down has made me look at it differently. I'll try again.

Answer (score 0):

Think this kind of problem is perfect for [BitArray's And method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.and.aspx).

Basically the `usernumbers` would be a `BitArray` instance, and you would have a list with the last 52 `BitArray` `lotterynumbers`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<BitArray> lotterynumbers = GetLastWinningNumbers();
    BitArray usernumbers = new BitArray(MAX_LOTTERY_NUMBER);

    Console.Write("Please enter six numbers for the lottery: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        usernumbers[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())] = true;

    BitArray bestmatches = new BitArray(MAX_LOTTERY_NUMBER);
    BitArray bestweek = bestmatches;
    foreach (BitArray weeknumbers in lotterynumbers)
    {
        BitArray currentmatches = usernumbers.And(weeknumbers);
        if (currentmatches.Count > bestmatches.Count)
        {
            bestmatches = currentmatches;
            bestweek = weeknumbers;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\n\nYour week with the most matches was...");
    foreach (int number in bestweek)
    {
        Console.Write(number);
        Console.Write(' ');
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress any key to continue: ");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```